# setting up pagekite with my own frontend to access ssh

Tags: reverse-proxy

I'm trying to expose my ssh server to my own frontend using Pagekite 0.5.6d on a linux box.

This is the line for my frontend:

```
./pagekite.py  --clean \
  --isfrontend \
  --ports=23456 \
  --domain=raw:client1.bla.ch:toto
```

This is the line for my client:

```
./pagekite.py --clean \  
  --frontend=nn.nn.nn.nn:23456 \
  --service_on=raw/22:client1.bla.ch:localhost:22:toto
```

If I try to launch the client, I get rejected with that line:

```
REJECTED: raw-22:client1.bla.ch (port)
```

And on my front end, there is a line like that that appears:

```
Connecting to front-end x.x.x.x:x ...
```

What could be wrong in my config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to BjarniRunar (one of the guy of Pagekite), adding the flag:

```
--rawports=virtual
```

do the tricks. Unfortunately, It seems that it's undocumented.